# How to log information from multiple threads into different files in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to log the different clients information in different files in python. ex client 1,client 2,client 3 in their specific files but in client 1 file all the information is coming 1,2,3 in client 2 file 2,3 information is coming.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Kindly give more information about your question.

Comment: Show us the relevant code, it's impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: May be you can create log file inside the threading code, so for example if 3 threads execute the code, all 3 of them will create a log file of its own.